# How do I get my 4-way switch to work correctly with two 3-way switches?

Tags: wiring

[image]I have two 3-way switches and one 4-way switch controlling multiple lights. When the 4-way is toggled up, one 3-way is toggled up and the other is down. These switches can turn the lights off and on (like 3-ways normally work). If the 4-way switch is toggled down then no switch will turn on the lights.

The 3-ways are both wired the same. Red wire on the bottom, black wire above that, and black wire coming from white wires wired together.

The 4-way is wired with one set of wires black on top black screw and red wire on top brass screw. The other set of wires black and red wires are wired the same on the bottom screws.

Comment: Can you show this in a diagram?

Comment: do not see how to add a diagram to the post

Comment: Thank you Harper! Found the problem. All good now.

Comment: Should accept Harper's answer if it helped you solved

Comment: @BrianM -- mind posting what you found as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

Top or bottom means nothing on a 3-way or 4-way switch.  What matters is the colors of the screws, or if they're not special, the markings.

I think you're assuming that switch manufacturers got together and made a standard for screw locations to make life easy for novices. Not the case at all. The screws are in random positions on every switch.

On the 3-way switch the travelers go on the brass screws.

On a 4-way, one cable of travelers go on brass, the other cable of travelers go on black screws.

[image]

*One possible wiring diagram.  The schematic is the same for all 3/4 way wiring diagrams.*